# How to translate TextSelectionToolbar labels(Copy, Cut,...) in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, windows, flutter, dart

How to translate `TextSelectionToolbar` button labels(Copy, Cut,...) in **Getx** or other packages?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add `flutter_localizations` into `pubspec.yaml`

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

2. `import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';` into main.dart
3. use `supportedLocales`

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('fa','IR'),
      ],
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
```